# Changing Firebase target with Chrome Extension results in auth/invalid-credential

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firebase-authentication, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

I've previously setup and followed these steps, and got it to work:
https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/quickstart-js/auth/chromextension/readme/#license

But cloning this extension, but with a different `Extension ID`, different `firebase instance` and `OAuth/key` setup, I've tried to follow the steps at least 3 separate times, but every time it fails at the last step, the login (the consent screen works though)

- Upload a fresh dummy extension (without `key` field in manifest.json) (But it is the exact same code as the working one)
- Get the `Chrome Extension ID`, and the `Public Key`, no problem
- Create `OAuth Client ID` with the `Extension ID`, configured consent screen, no problem, the screen shows up and I can click through
- Add `OAuth` & `Public Key` to `manifest.json`
- Make another `OAuth Client ID`? (I think this is a duplicate step, because which `Client ID` should I use? and afaik the whitelisting is optional)
- Use `chrome.identity` to get OAuth token:

```js
export function startAuth(interactive) { 
  // Request an OAuth token from the Chrome Identity API.
  chrome.identity
    .getAuthToken({ interactive: !!interactive }, (token) => {
      if (chrome.runtime && !interactive) { 
        console.error('It was not possible to get a token programmatically.');
      }

      else if (token) {
        // Authorize Firebase with the OAuth Access Token.
        const credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider
          .credential(null, token);

        firebase.auth()
          .signInWithCredential(credential)
          .catch((error) => {
            // The OAuth token might have been invalidated. Lets' remove it from cache.
            if (error.code === 'auth/invalid-credential') {

              chrome.identity
                .removeCachedAuthToken({ token }, () => {
                  startAuth(interactive);
                });
            }
          });
      }

      else {
        console.error('The OAuth Token was null');
      }
    });
}
```

Note: **This code is working** with another extensionID/OAuth/key, so the code itself can't be the problem.

There isn't much to change between them, it's really the ExtensionID, the OAuth client ID url, and the public key.

I've followed the steps 3 times, to no avail, every time I get the error `auth/invalid-credential`. I **do** get a `token` though, but that token won't authenticate. How to find out why this is?

It's trying to post to this address, and returning error `400`:

```
POST:  https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithIdp?key=xxxxx
```

Error: `INVALID_IDP_RESPONSE : Invalid Idp Response: access_token audience is not for this project`

### My conclusion

There must be something changed with how to set this up, even though it works with different credentials

Comment: I cam across this: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/634 It seems that it's a matter of time before this all completely breaks and we are limited using firebase with extensions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I didn't create the OAuth in **the same project** in **google cloud console**, as the **firebase project**...